# Error in R "undefined columns selected"

Tags: r

I am trying to initiate this code using the zoo command:

```
gld <- zoo(gld[,7], gld_dates)
```

Unfortunately I get an error message telling me this:

> ```
> Error in `[.data.frame`(gld, , 7) : undefined columns selected
> ```

I want to use the zoo function to create zoo objects from my data.
The function should take two arguments: a vector of data and
a vector of dates.

This is [the data I am using](http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GLD&a=08&b=13&c=2007&d=08&e=13&f=2011&g=d&ignore=.csv)[LINK BROKEN].

I believe I have have 7 columns in my data set. Any ideas?

The code I am trying to implement is [found here](http://quanttrader.info/public/testForCoint.html)[LINK BROKEN].

Is their anything wrong with this code?

Comment: It might be worth double checking the number of columns: you can use the `ncol` function for this.

Comment: I just ran all the `gld` parts of the code from your website without errors. Could you reload your data and then run the command `str(gld)` and post the results so we can be sure you're starting in the right place?

Comment: Well what was the problem? and the solution?

Answer (score 5):

You don't say what your `gld_dates` is exactly, but if `gld` starts as your original data and you want to make a zoo object of the 7th column ordering by the 1st column (dates), I can do

```
gld_zoo <- zoo(gld[, 7], gld[, 1])
```

just fine. Equivalently, but with  more readability,

```
gld_zoo <- zoo(gld$Adj.close, gld$Date)
```

reminds me what each column is.

Comment: `gld_dates <- as.Date(gld[,1])`

Comment: This is where I am getting my code.  http://quanttrader.info/public/testForCoint.html

Answer (score 0):

Subsetting requires the names of the subset columns to match those in the data frame. This code subsets the dataset `french_fries` with `potat` instead of `potato`:

```r
data("french_fries")
df_potato <- french_fries[, c("potatoes")]
```

and it fails with:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(french_fries, , c("potatoes")) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

but using the right name `potato` works:

```r
df_potato <- french_fries[, c("potato")]
```